# Handling browser refresh with query filters from page parameters

Tags: google-app-maker

I have two data sources

1. Assets
2. Locations

Assets has a One to Many relation with Locations

Assets has a query builder data source, AssetLocFiltered, that is set with the following:

```
ParentLocationKey =:ParentLocationKey
```

ParentLocationKey is the relation field for the locations table.

On the home page you select a location and then click a button that passes the location ID to a parameter on the ShopPageDemo page. with the following code

```
app.pages.ShopPageDemo.properties.ParentLocationKey = 
widget.datasource.item.Id;
console.log(widget.datasource.item.Id);
app.showPage(app.pages.ShopPageDemo);
```

One the ShopPageDemo Page there is a table view of the AssetLocFiltered that sets the query parameter in the ondataload event with the following code:

```
widget.root.datasource.query.parameters.ParentLocationKey = 
widget.root.properties.ParentLocationKey;
widget.root.datasource.load();
```

This works great. The problem is when i hit the browser refresh it seems like it clears the property in ShopPageDemo. How do I handle this browser refresh issue? I am not really sure where to start.

Comment: Might need to look at using browser cookies for that or possible implement the CacheService here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/cache-service. However, if you use the cache service I am not entirely certain how long the information gets stored for and then you would also need to implement this back into your application and call a script on app load to retrieve the cache. Is this an accidental browser refresh, or why would you refresh the browser?

Comment: trying to account for an accidental refresh. I was thinking i could also log this in a table, just not sure how i would retrieve it after a refresh. Maybe in a startup script? not sure if that runs on a browser refresh, or how i could tell the difference between a refresh and normal startup.

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one way to do this; However, the approach I usually take involves deep linking. In your case, you'll need to do something like this:

1.) On the button that takes you to the next page, add this code:

```
var params = {
  key: widget.datasource.item.Id
};    
var page = app.pages.ShopPageDemo;
app.showPage(page);
google.script.history.replace(null, params, page.name);
```

2.) On the **ShopPageDemo** *onAttach* event handler, add the following:

```
google.script.url.getLocation(function(location) {
  widget.root.properties.ParentLocationKey = location.parameter.key;
  var ds = widget.datasource;
  ds.query.parameters.ParentLocationKey = widget.root.properties.ParentLocationKey;
  ds.load();
});
```

For better performance, I would set the **ShopPageDemo** datasource to NOT load automatically and also to unload its data on the *onDetach* event handler like this: `widget.datasource.unload()`.

Reference: 
1.  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/history

2.  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/url

Comment: Having some trouble getting it working. Seems like the getlocation script is not returning anything tried cosole.log(location.parameter.key) and its coming out as a null

Comment: @kylelove41 You must be doing something wrong. Does the URL change when you click on the button that takes you to the ShopPageDemo?

Comment: Yes, URL is changing

Comment: @kylelove41 Well, in that case, can't really tell what you are doing wrong since I don't know how your code and how your environment looks. This method has worked for me on several apps. Good luck!